# What is the non-relativistic differential equation for the helium atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I understand that the Schrodinger Equation for the hydrogen atom is

$$E\Psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi+V\Psi$$

with $$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\Psi+V\Psi$$ being the Hamiltonian

and I understand that the [Hamiltonian of the Helium Atom](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/09%3A_The_Electronic_States_of_the_Multielectron_Atoms/9.01%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation_For_Multi-Electron_Atoms) is

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\nabla_1^2\Psi+\nabla_2^2\Psi\right)+V_1\Psi+V_2\Psi+V_{12}\Psi$$

although I haven't seen what's on the other side of the equation

As I understand it each electron can also be in a different energy level from the other

So is the non relativistic differential equation for the Helium atom

$$E_1\Psi+E_2\Psi=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\nabla_1^2\Psi+\nabla_2^2\Psi\right)+V_1\Psi+V_2\Psi+V_{12}\Psi$$

or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what $E_1 + E_2$ are supposed to be - probably there is no such separation into a sum (and the last equation is missing a wavefunction) - but generally, well, you're right, the *time-independent* Schrödinger equation for a system (including the Helium atom) is the eigenvalue equation
$$
E \Psi = \widehat{H}\Psi
$$
for the energy $E$ of the system described by the wavefunction $\Psi$ and with the Hamiltonian operator $\widehat{H}$.

Comment: I did forget to add the wavefunction to the left of the last equation, so i added it now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also I know that I can't do $\Psi(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1,r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)=\Psi(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)\Psi(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$ because there's a $V(r_1,r_2)$ but would doing something like $\Psi(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1,r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)=A_1(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1,r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)A_2(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1,r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$ be useful?

Comment: No. What for and how? The separation ansatz reduces complexity of the problem, you suggestion does not.

Comment: The idea I have for $A_1$ and $A_2$ is to approximate the function $A_1$ at each $(r_2,\theta_2,\phi_2)$, and approximate the function $A_2$ at each $(r_1,\theta_1,\phi_1)$